# Which is better in terms of performance ToUpper of C# or Upper function in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have a situation where I can use ToUpper() in codebehind or I can use Upper of SQL in the stored procedures. It got me thinking as to using which would be better? I don't think it will be a major performance improvement, but I would like to know using which would be better and when

Comment: In situations such as this you should benchmark/profile to determine which is better.

Comment: How many string have you got to uppercase? It would have to be a lot to make any sort of difference...

Comment: i would suggest to use the Upper function in MSSQL

Comment: I don't know if it helps you: we had a case of a long stored procedure with lots of string operations, like replacements (lots means about 10 per call) where the database suffers performance. We took the logic out of the SP into the code behind and the performance was improved by factor 10 (very subjective scale).

Comment: @Matten, I agree from both a performance standpoint (since the database already has to handle so much why make it do more) and from a design standpoint

Comment: As the mentioned application was designed the creator thought it would be a great idea to place the entire business logic on the data layer and to make the presentation logic as stupid and simple as possible. Turns out to be a very bad idea as MSSQL 2000 had some bad performance issues. With precompiled xp's on SQL 2005 maybe the situation would have changed, but I don't like to join business and data layer.

Comment: I have a string collection of about 100 odd strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm one of those, Database should only do data kind of guys. Personally, I would prefer ToUpper() in C# because that's where your logic belongs not in the database. The only performance hit would be having to parse the toupper in the sql but I'm pretty sure that SPROC's get optimized so there might not even be a difference as far as I can tell.

From my experience, don't make the DB work harder than it has to, doing a lot of these operations will probably show performance hits on the database (for a large amount of strings, probably negligible for small amounts)

Comment: Finally someone else who gets 3-tier/n-tier architecture :D

Answer (score 1):

I will not go to which one is *correct*, because that is subjective, and depends on your application's architecture and your internal standards.

Doing on the database may have performance impacts depending on the scenario and the data.

Let us say you have an `ORDER` table with a column `STATUS_CODE` which will have only upper case values (referenced from a master table let us say). Now if you want to get all orders placed on `1 Apr 2011` that are in status "CLOSED", and this "CLOSED" comes from a UI dropdown, and can have both lower and upper case (for whatever reason).

Here doing upper on the database or in C# should not make much difference.

```
select *
from order
where order_date  = '1 Apr 2011'
and status_code = upper(:status_code)
```

But let us say your (ok, mine) `order` table does not refer to any master table and may have both upper and lower case values (this is not good db design). You may do the following:

```
select *
from order
where order_date  = '1 Apr 2011'
and upper(status_code) = upper(:status_code)
```

which may have serious performance problems depending on the data in the table. 
For one oracle will be unable to use the index on the `status_code` column (if there is one).

Answer (score -1):

1) if you use ToUpper in C#, and don't want to use UPPER in SP, you can have a situation when another part in C# don't use ToUpper when executes this SP and you can recive wrong results
2) strings operations are very heavy; if your server will be really busy, string operations will be first candidates to move them from server to client.